# AD: Unable to perform remote desktop logon

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2016

For my users in Active Directory, I did setup a GPO in order to allow the remote desktop connections.

For a specific user in particular, I did also manually setup the group membership for *Remote Desktop Users*:

[image]

However, I still get an error while performing a remote logon, saying that the user is not allowed to login in remotely.

Do you have any clue about it?
Please just consider that Admins can correctly perform this operation, and the target machine is a generic windows server machine (no specific role yet installed, just joined to the domain).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For my users in Active Directory, I did setup a GPO in order to allow
>   the remote desktop connections.

What specifically did you configure in the GPO?

> For a specific user in particular, I did also manually setup the group
>   membership for Remote Desktop Users.

Did you add this user to the domain Remote Desktop Users group in Active Directory Users and Computers or did you add them to the local Remote Desktop Users on the server itself? You need to add them to the local Remote Desktop Users group on the server itself.

Comment: I added the user to the Remote Desktop User group directly in Active Directory Users and Computers. About the GPO, I did follow this guide: https://thesysadminchannel.com/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-via-group-policy-gpo/

Comment: The GPO setting is correct but the user must also be a member of the local Remote Desktop Users group on the server itself. Add the user to the local Remote Desktop Users group.

Comment: Is there no programmatic way to do it? I am looking for is a mean to automatically grant this privilege to all users in a given OU for all computers belonging to a particular group.

Comment: Sure. You could use Group Policy Preferences to populate the local Remote Desktop Users group on the servers.

Comment: Couldn't he just add the AD group to the local group? Or alternatively grant the AD group the same user rights that the local group has?

Comment: Yes, he could add the domain group to the local group. The point is that the user needs to be a member of the local group, either directly or as a member of another group which is a member of the local group. RDP access requires two things: User Rights and Permissions. User rights can be granted locally or via domain based GPO. Permissions can only be granted locally by making the user a member of the local group.